# Can I add registry to gateway jhipster app?

Tags: registry, jhipster, netflix-eureka

Can I add registry support to an gateway app created without registry?
I have an gateway app, when I created this app, I don't select jhipster registry.
It is posible? Or do I need to add line by line eureka configuration?

```
eureka:
    client:
        enabled: true
        healthcheck:
            enabled: true
        fetch-registry: true
        register-with-eureka: true
        instance-info-replication-interval-seconds: 10
        registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 10
    instance:
        appname: cadgateway
        instanceId: cadgateway:${spring.application.instance-id:${random.value}}
        lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5
        lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 10
        status-page-url-path: ${management.context-path}/info
        health-check-url-path: ${management.context-path}/health
        metadata-map:
            zone: primary # This is needed for the load balancer
            profile: ${spring.profiles.active}
            version: ${info.project.version}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `.yo-rc.json` file and change the line `"serviceDiscoveryType": false,` to `"serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",` then re-generate your app with `jhipster app --with-entities` and merge with git the customizations you might have done.